# How to use rasterio transform on all bands

Tags: python, rasterio

I've imported a 10 band raster tif using rasterio as ds.  I'm attempting to pad the image but keep getting errors with the transform.

```
print(ds.transform)
pilpadimg = rasterio.pad(ds.read(), transform=ds.transform, pad_width=((0,0),(1,2),(3,4)), mode='reflect')

| 15.00, 0.00, 344117.00|
| 0.00,-15.00, 5082412.00|
| 0.00, 0.00, 1.00|
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-77-9526c3dd4939> in <module>
      1 print(ds.transform)
----> 2 pilpadimg = rasterio.pad(ds.read(), transform=ds.transform.identity(), pad_width=((0,0),(1,2),(3,4)), mode='reflect')

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\pytorch\lib\site-packages\rasterio\__init__.py in pad(array, transform, pad_width, mode, **kwargs)
    279     padded_array = np.pad(array, pad_width, mode, **kwargs)
    280     padded_trans = list(transform)
--> 281     padded_trans[2] -= pad_width * padded_trans[0]
    282     padded_trans[5] -= pad_width * padded_trans[4]
    283     return padded_array, Affine(*padded_trans[:6])

TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'
```

It works great with numpy but there is no transform..

```
>>> x = np.ones((8,3,3))
>>> np.pad(x, pad_width=((0,0),(1,2),(3,4)), mode='constant', constant_values=0)
```

pad_width has to be an int and the transform is a float.  I converted the transform list to int and still get the same error

EDIT:
Fixed by simply using numpy to pad instead of rasterio

```
pilpadimg = np.pad(ds.read(),pad_width=[(0,0),(1,2),(3,4)], mode='reflect')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rasterio's docs for [`pad`](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/rasterio.html?highlight=int#rasterio.pad) say:

```
pad_width: int
    number of pixels to pad array on all four sides
```

So you need to pass a single value, not `numpy`'s sequence of before/after values:

```
pilpadimg = rasterio.pad(ds.read(), transform=ds.transform, pad_width=42, mode='reflect')
```

Comment: Ahh.  Based on the numpy documentation I assumed it worked similarly and would take a tuple.  Thank you

Comment: I decided to just use numpy.
pilpadimg = np.pad(ds.read(),pad_width=[(0,0),(1,2),(3,4)], mode='reflect')

Comment: You can always recalculate the new origin of the affine if you still need georeferencing.

Comment: That's exactly what I plan to do Marc!  Thanks.  Time to learn something new.